# Delete a directory ending with build numbers

Tags: shell, directory

I have a path where there will be build directories copied, so i need to keep only latest 3 directories and delete others, not by date but with the latest build number.

If i have the following directories in the path /tmp

```
1.1.0000-21, 1.1.0000-5, 1.1.0000-18, 1.1.0000-4
```

I should be deleting `1.1.0000-4` directory in `/tmp` path as its the oldest directory.

I was trying with `rm -rf /base/path -type d -ctime 4` , but this is based on latest file, not sure about getting oldest number to delete, do i need some reg-ex here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine `sort` and `tail` for this

```
ls \          # Produce the list of directories,
| sort -r \   #  reorder it in reverse dictionary order
| tail -n +5  #  and trim the first 4 = 5-1 entries
```

This assumes that the version order coincides with dictionary order, which is false if your version have not fixed length (so version 2.0 will look newer as 12.0). You can fix this by adapting the call to the the sort function.

Comment: Yes Michael, length is not fixed. i have updated my question with folder names. I found that build number 1st digit is taken after hyphen (-)  so, if there are XXXXXX-84, XXXXXX-2, XXXXXX-114 and XXXXXX-3 then 114,2 and 3 will be taken as the new build (or exact reverse), which is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your help Michael. Following will work if all my builds are in same order of increment(mostly it will be).  ls |sort -nr |tail -n +4 |xargs rm -rf